# How to map Cassandra Tuple collection in Java entity

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, tuples, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a cassandra table with a **set-of-tuple** column as below,

```
ref_nums set<frozen<tuple<text,text>>>;
```

I want to map this into my Java entity. I am using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra v2.0.4.RELEASE which leads to a driver version,

```
<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
```

1. How to map it?
2. What will be java entity configuration if I use UDT in place of tuple?
3. What is the difference between using UDT and using tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem with built in dependency of spring boot.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

By the above configuration, we are replacing spring's own dependency of spring-data-cassandra (some previous version) and in addition to it we need spring-data-commons